# Cannot get my menu code to work with my rock paper scissors code

Tags: c, menu

I have two separate sets of code. One of a menu and the other of a rock paper scissors game. Im not sure how to link the two. Im pretty new to C and have been scrawling the internet looking for answers but I keep coming up with nothing. Im not sure what to look for either.

```
#define _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS
// C program for the above approach
#include <math.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <windows.h>
#include <conio.h>




//UDF declaration
int inapp(); //UDF inapp
int exitapp(); //UDF exit app
int exitapp(); //UDF mainmenu

int menu = 0;


int mainmenu(int x) {



    system("cls");
    printf("Welcome to Rock Paper Scissors! \n---------------------\n\nc To continue \nb To exit\n");
    int menumain = _getch();

    while (1) {
        if (menumain == 'c') { //checks if the user is in the app, then makes it so they go to the inapp
            inapp();

        }
        else if (menumain == 'b') { // checks
            exitapp();
        }
        else {
            printf("\nNah. I don't get it.");
            Sleep(1000);
            mainmenu(1);
        }
    }
}

//In app function
int inapp() {



    system("cls");
    printf("Welcome to the menu.\n\n0 to exit \n1 to continue\n2 to return\n");
    //scanf_s("%d", &menuin);
    printf("\nPlease enter your choice\n");
    char menuin = _getch();

    if (menuin == '0') {
        exitapp();
    }
    else if (menuin == '1') {
        ;
    }
    else if (menuin == '2') {
        mainmenu(1);
    }
    else {
        printf("\nNah. I don't get it.");
        Sleep(1000);
        inapp();
    }

}

//Exit app function
int exitapp() {

    system("cls");

    printf("Goodbye, and thank you for your time.\n\n");
    exit(0);
}

// Function to implement the game
int game(char you, char computer)
{
    // If both the user and computer
    // has chose the same thing
    if (you == computer)
        return -1;

    // If user's choice is stone and
    // computer's choice is paper
    if (you == 's' && computer == 'p')
        return 0;

    // If user's choice is paper and
    // computer's choice is stone
    else if (you == 'p' && computer == 's') return 1;

    // If user's choice is stone and
    // computer's choice is scissor
    if (you == 's' && computer == 'z')
        return 1;

    // If user's choice is scissor and
    // computer's choice is stone
    else if (you == 'z' && computer == 's')
        return 0;

    // If user's choice is paper and
    // computer's choice is scissor
    if (you == 'p' && computer == 'z')
        return 0;

    // If user's choice is scissor and
    // computer's choice is paper
    else if (you == 'z' && computer == 'p')
        return 1;
}

// Driver Code
int main()
{

    // Stores the random number
    int n;

    char you, computer, result;

    // Chooses the random number
    // every time
    srand((unsigned int)time(NULL));

    // Make the random number less
    // than 100, divided it by 100
    n = rand() % 100;

    // Using simple probability 100 is
    // roughly divided among stone,
    // paper, and scissor
    if (n < 33)

        // s is notating Stone
        computer = 's';

    else if (n > 33 && n < 66)

        // p is notating Paper
        computer = 'p';

    // z is notating Scissors
    else
        computer = 'z';

    printf("\n\n\n\n\t\t\t\tEnter s for STONE, p for PAPER and z for SCISSOR\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t");

    // this is the input from the user
    scanf("%c", &you);

    // Function Call to play the game
    result = game(you, computer);

    if (result == -1) {
        printf("\n\n\t\t\t\tGame Draw!\n");
    }
    else if (result == 1) {
        printf("\n\n\t\t\t\tWow! You have won the game!\n");
    }
    else {
        printf("\n\n\t\t\t\tOh! You have lost the game!\n");
    }
    printf("\t\t\t\tYOu choose : %c and Computer choose : %c\n", you, computer);
    
    return 0;
}
```

I have all the errors gone and the rock paper scissors game works but the menu isnt showing up. I don't know what else to search for or what the issue is.

Comment: As `'\n'` is a character too, `_getch();` might read a `'\n'`, yet code does not handle that.  Post exact input used and output seen for details.

Comment: On a minor note, consider what if `n==33`, what branch is taken in `if (n < 33) computer = 's'; else if (n > 33 && n < 66) computer = 'p'; else  computer = 'z';`?

Comment: I'v only been coding in C for about 2 months so im not sure what to make of that

Answer (score 0):

The entry for your program is `main()` and it doesn't call either `mainmenu()` or `inapp()`.  `mainmenu()` and `inapp()` seems to be doing the same thing so let's eliminate `inapp()`.

Looking at `mainmenu()` it seems `c` is what should invoke our game.  To do that we rename `main()` to `rock_paper_scissors()` and rename `mainmenu(int x)` to `int main()`.  We can use a switch instead of the if-else if-else to make it a little cleaner.  Also, you don't want to call `mainmenu()` recursively as stack space is finite.  Just loop around instead.  In terms of user experience, it's better to just start the game and then ask if user wants to continue.

I don't use windows but `getchar()` gets a byte from the stdin, but it's line buffered so we have to ignore everything that comes after till we read a newline.  I will call that function `getchar_and_flush()`.  You wan to use this instead of `scanf()` to read the choice from user.

There are other issues with your program.  For instance, if `n == 33` the computer will elect `z` which is surprising.  Those single letter symbols makes your code hard to read.  I suggest you introduce `enum symbol { ROCK, PAPER, SCISSORS }` and use that instead of `s`, `p`, and `z`.  You sometimes call it rock, other times stone (internally inconsistent).  The `game()` function looks weird to me as you sometimes you `if` and sometimes `else if`.  There a much better trick, namely, a table.  Let's first rename the result, using an enum:

```
enum result {
    LOSS = -1,
    TIE,
    WIN
};
```

| you \ computer | rock | paper | scissors |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| rock | TIE | LOSS | WIN |
| paper | WIN | TIE | LOSS |
| scissor | LOSS | WIN | TIE |

which can directly expressed as a 2d array (see `game()`).

After cleaning up the prompts, and removing windows specific features the code now looks like this:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <unistd.h>

enum result {
    LOSS = -1,
    TIE,
    WIN
};

enum symbol {
    ROCK,
    PAPER,
    SCISSORS,
    INVALID
};

struct {
    enum symbol s;
    char c;
    const char *name;
} map[] = {
    { ROCK, 'r', "rock" },
    { PAPER, 'p', "paper" },
    { SCISSORS, 's', "scissors" },
    { INVALID, '?' }
};

int getchar_and_flush() {
    int c = getchar();
    while(getchar() != '\n');
    return c;
}

const char *name_from_symbol(enum symbol s) {
    for(size_t i = 0; i < sizeof map / sizeof *map; i++)
        if(s == map[i].s)
            return map[i].name;
    return map[INVALID].name;
}

enum symbol symbol_from_char(char c) {
    for(size_t i = 0; i < sizeof map / sizeof *map; i++)
        if(c == map[i].c)
            return map[i].s;
    return INVALID;
}

int game(enum symbol you, enum symbol computer) {
    return (enum result [3][3]) {
        { TIE,  LOSS, WIN },
        { WIN,  TIE,  LOSS },
        { LOSS, WIN,  TIE }
    }[you][computer];
}

void rock_paper_scissor() {
    enum symbol computer;
    srand((unsigned int)time(NULL));
    int n = rand() % 100;
    if (n < 33)
        computer = ROCK;
    else if (n < 66)
        computer = PAPER;
    else
        computer = SCISSORS;
    enum symbol you;
    do {
        printf("Enter r for ROCK, p for PAPER and s for SCISSORS: ");
        you = symbol_from_char(getchar_and_flush());
        if(you == INVALID)
           printf("Invalid input\n");
    } while(you == INVALID);
    switch(game(you, computer)) {
        case LOSS:
            printf("Oh! You have lost the game!\n");
            break;
        case TIE:
            printf("Game Draw!\n");
            break;
        case WIN:
            printf("Wow! You have won the game!\n");
            break;
    }
    printf(
        "You choose : %s and Computer choose : %s\n"
        "\n",
        name_from_symbol(you), name_from_symbol(computer)
    );
}

int main() {
    printf(
        "Welcome to Rock Paper Scissors!\n"
        "-------------------------------\n"
        "\n"
    );
    for(;;) {
        rock_paper_scissor();
        printf("Again (y/n)? ");
        switch(getchar_and_flush()) {
            case 'y':
                printf("\n");
                continue;
                break;
            case 'n':
                printf("Goodbye, and thank you for your time.\n");
                return 0;
            default:
                printf("Nah. I don't get it.\n");
                break;
        }
    }
}
```

and example session:

```
Welcome to Rock Paper Scissors!
-------------------------------

Enter r for ROCK, p for PAPER and s for SCISSORS: r
Oh! You have lost the game!
You choose : rock and Computer choose : paper

Again (y/n)? y

Enter r for ROCK, p for PAPER and s for SCISSORS: r
Game Draw!
You choose : rock and Computer choose : rock

Again (y/n)? y

Enter r for ROCK, p for PAPER and s for SCISSORS: s
Wow! You have won the game!
You choose : scissors and Computer choose : paper

Again (y/n)? n
Goodbye, and thank you for your time.
```

Answer (score 0):

**NOT INTENDED AS AN ANSWER** (please do not DV)

If your ambition is to become a coder, you have to learn to break apart a problem and produce a good solution. Your version of `game()` is long and convoluted.

Study the following and see how it serves to compare the two players' selections with only a few lines of code. (This could be further reduced when you learn about modulo arithmetic.)

```
int game( char you, char computer ) {
    if( you == computer ) return -1;
    if( you == 's' )    return computer == 'z'; // stone/scissors wins
    if( you == 'p' )    return computer == 's'; // paper/stone wins
/*  if( you == 'z' ) */ return computer == 'p'; // scissors/paper wins
}
```

Notice that `else` is not necessary. When the `if()` evaluates true, the execution is already diverted by `return;`

With less code to read, the answer to your question will not be hidden in too many lines of code and you may be able to solve it for yourself.

**EDIT**
Following the (customary) excellent answer from @AllanWind and in support of his demonstration of using a *look up table* to determine the results of a combination, the following shows how one might implement the slightly more complicated decisions of Sheldon Cooper's Variation:
"Rock/Paper/Scissors/Lizard/Spock".

In brief, the user makes a selection from the terse menu and a similar random(!) selection is made for the PC. Then `evaluate` performs a table lookup to determine the winner and the appropriate string to explain the basis of the winning relationship.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

char *dr = "DRAW\n\n";

char *sp = "scissors cuts paper";
char *pr = "paper covers rock";
char *rl = "rock crushes lizard";
char *ln = "lizard poisons Spock";
char *ns = "Spock smashes scissors";
char *sl = "scissors decapitates lizard";
char *lp = "lizard eats paper";
char *pn = "paper disproves Spock";
char *nr = "Spock vaporizes rock";
char *rs = "rock crushes scissors";

char *tbl[][6] = {
    { dr, pr, rs, rl, nr, " lwwl", },
    { pr, dr, sp, lp, pn, "w llw", },
    { rs, sp, dr, sl, ns, "lw wl", },
    { rl, lp, sl, dr, ln, "lwl w", },
    { nr, pn, ns, ln, dr, "wlwl ", },
};

void evaluate( int usr, int cpu ) {
    char *elems[] = { "rock", "paper", "scissors", "lizard", "nimoy(spock)" };
    printf ( "\nYou: %-14s - PC: %-14s - %s", elems[ usr ], elems[ cpu ], tbl[usr][cpu] );
    if( usr != cpu )
        printf( " - %s\n\n", tbl[usr][5][cpu] == 'w' ? "WIN!!" : "lose..." );
}

void oneRound() {
    char *choices = "rpslnRPSLN";
    char buf[32];

    printf( "choose [r]ock [p]aper [s]cissors [l]izard [n]imoy(Spock): " );
    fgets( buf, sizeof buf, stdin );
    char *cp = strchr( choices, buf[0] );
    if( cp == NULL )
        puts( "bad entry" );
    else
        evaluate( ( cp - choices ) % 5, rand() % 5 );
}

int main() {
    srand( time(NULL) );
    for( ;; )
        oneRound();

    return 0;
}
```

```
choose [r]ock [p]aper [s]cissors [l]izard [n]imoy(Spock): n

You: nimoy(spock)   - PC: paper          - paper disproves Spock - lose...

choose [r]ock [p]aper [s]cissors [l]izard [n]imoy(Spock): r

You: rock           - PC: paper          - paper covers rock - lose...

choose [r]ock [p]aper [s]cissors [l]izard [n]imoy(Spock): r

You: rock           - PC: nimoy(spock)   - Spock vaporizes rock - lose...

choose [r]ock [p]aper [s]cissors [l]izard [n]imoy(Spock): l

You: lizard         - PC: rock           - rock crushes lizard - lose...

choose [r]ock [p]aper [s]cissors [l]izard [n]imoy(Spock):
```

Of note may be the very few lines of code at the heart of this program. "Window dressing" of user interaction can be added to taste.